# What's the definition of top-level in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I read across the language reference plenty of references to this concept,

> Set the name of the project, and stores it in the variable `PROJECT_NAME`. When called from the *top-level* `CMakeLists.txt` also stores the project name in the variable `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME`.

however I am unable to find its definition.

Please provide a source. =)

source: [https://cmake.org/cmake/command/project.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html)

Comment: Converted comment to answer as requested. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit older documentation [http://cmake.org/examples](https://cmake.org/examples) but may still help. I guess most people just implicitly assume (correctly) that the top-level CMakeLists.txt is just the one which has no other CMake files in the folder above it. :)

Answer (score 2):

When configure a project using CMake, you need to specify **source directory** and **build directory**. The *top-level* `CMakeLists.txt` is the one located in the **source directory**. This `CMakeLists.txt` is processed first.

Other `CMakeLists.txt` are usually included via `add_subdirectory` command, so they are usually located in the *subdirectories*. This is why firstly processed `CMakeLists.txt` is referred as "top-level" one.

Comment: Would you be so kind so as to provide a source? =)

Comment: I have no source for given definition. From my understanding, it is obvious and well-known.